# Openpyxl, Date time -writing only first cell

Tags: datetime, openpyxl, timedelta

I want to write the names of a set of video files with their corresponding file length to an excel sheet. The list of video populates in the first column. The **length** of the video does not populate in the excel sheet.

```
Video1.mp4   | 03:23
Video2.mp4   | 09:33
Video3.mp4   | 04:77
Video4.mp4   | 02:00
```

I want to populate the names of the video in column1
and length of the videos in columnB.

```
import os
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4
from datetime import timedelta
from openpyxl import Workbook

path = r'C:\Users\Me\videos'
wb = Workbook()
ws=wb.active

for files in os.listdir(path):
    full = os.path.join(path, files)
    audio = MP4(full)
    formated = timedelta(seconds=audio.info.length)
    ws.cell(row=1, column=2).value = timedelta(seconds=audio.info.length)
    print(formated)
for r in range(0,len(os.listdir(path))):
    ws.cell(row=r+1,column=1).value= os.listdir(path)[r]
wb.save('text.xlsx')
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: The length of the videos is not populating in excel

Comment: Well, you are overwriting the same cell each time with a different file.

Comment: How can I write into the columns, did this inside the same column and got the entire column filled the the same item.     for r in range(0, len(os.listdir(path))):
ws.cell(row=r+1, column=2).value = formated

Comment: Please provide a sample of the output you want. I think you'll be best off using `ws.append()`